# Ajax - Onchange show/Hide

Tags: html, ajax

I just have a quick question about Ajax.
So, I've this little Scriptcode.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Reisemittel").onChange(function(){
     //   alert($('#Reisemittel option:selected').val());
     var inhalt = $('#Reisemittel option:selected').val();

    })
});

if(inhalt.style.display == "block") {
        inhalt.style.display = "none";

}
else {
    inhalt.style.display = "block";

}
```

}

Then I got this Html Select Option

```
     <select id="Reisemittel" size=1>
                    <option value=0>bitte wählen...</option>
                    <option value="EigenesFahrzeug">Eigenes Fahrzeug</option>
                    <option value="BINOSFahrzeug">BINOS Fahrzeug/Mietwagen</option>
                    <option value="Flug">Flug</option>                    
                    <option value="Bahn">Bahn</option>     
                </select>
```

What I want too try, is when I change the Value in the Select Option to "EigenesFahrzeug"

```
          <div id="EigenesFahrzeug" style="display: none;">Test </div>
```

that this Div will show

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#Reisemittel").change(function(event) {
                var id = $(event.target).val();
                $(".toggleable").hide();
                var inhalt = $("#" + id);
                inhalt.show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="Reisemittel" size=1>
    <option value=0>bitte wählen...</option>
    <option value="EigenesFahrzeug">Eigenes Fahrzeug</option>
    <option value="BINOSFahrzeug">BINOS Fahrzeug/Mietwagen</option>
    <option value="Flug">Flug</option>
    <option value="Bahn">Bahn</option>
</select>
<div id="EigenesFahrzeug" class="toggleable" style="display:none;">
    EigenesFahrzeug!!!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll notice that I use the jquery method `change` instead of `onChange`. You'll also see that the function I pass into `change` takes the event as an argument. You'll see that I'm using the jquery method `toggle` to show/hide the div. You should be able to take it from here!

Comment: Thank you Sir,
your Code works well, but I got one Question. I'm pretty new in this business. So if I toggle one, then go to the next, the last one stays toggled. How can I fix this?

Comment: I have edited the answer to support this. I did this by adding a class `toggleable` to the divs that I want to hide. Then in the event handling function, I call `$(".toggleable").hide()` to hide them all before showing the one we are interested in.

Welcome to the business!

Comment: Thank you, have a nice day Sir!

*waving*

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `toggle()` for that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Reisemittel").on('change', function(){
        var inhalt = $('#Reisemittel option:selected').val();
        $('#EigenesFahrzeug').toggle(inhalt == 'EigenesFahrzeug');
    })
});
```

Your current code does not work because the condition is outside the `onChange()` handler (and also, `inhalt` is a value, not an element).